# Generalized eigenspaces

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to study more about generalized eigenspaces. Can you please guide me about some good texts which have dicussed generalized eigenspaces in more clear and complete ways? I have also read David Vogan's lecture notes on the subject and I've found the lecture notes very good. But I would also like to study generalized eigenspace from a good textbook too. I've also read chapter 8 of Sheldon Axler's book.

Comment: You could try Lax's Linear Algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend chapter 7 of Friedberg, Insel and Spence's  $Linear ~Algebra$, 4th edition, 2003.

Comment: Are you sure it is chapter 7? My 4th edition only has six chapters...